# Type hints and variable reassignment with different type

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am getting a error `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "bytes")` on a code below.

```py
import sys

from typing import BinaryIO


def fn1(stream: BinaryIO = sys.stdin.buffer):
    for line in stream:
        line = line.decode('utf-8').replace(' ', '').strip()  # <- error here
        x, y = line.split('|')  # <- error here
        print(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fn1()
```

mypy's output:

```
script.py:8: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", variable has type "bytes")
script.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "split" of "bytes" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Optional[bytes]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

How to suggest mypy that the line is a string, not bytes? I don't want to refactor a code and add new line ... aka:

```
line = line.decode('utf-8')  # new line ... but its works
line = line.replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce this, please provide more context and the output error

Comment: I think its complaining about reading buffer (which is bytes) as string while doing `for line in stream`. Try this: `for line in stream.decode('utf-8').split('\n')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible.

So the straightest solution is to use different names for different types.

```
for b_line in stream:
    line = b_line.decode('utf-8').replace(' ', '').strip()
```

Rationale is that otherwise it might be totally unpredictable for mypy when your variable means what, like here:

```
while ...:
   a = 's'
   ...possible break...
   a = 1

a + 2  # impossible to verify correctness
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't want to refactor the code. But apparently this is necessary.